# Access Sum of Nested CountIfs

Tags: sql, ms-access, calculated-columns

I have 5 fields in my table:

```
PTS, AST, REB, BLK, STL
```

I want to add a calculated field that is equal to 3 if two of those fields equal 10 or more and is equal to 6 if three or more of those fields equal 10 or more.

For example, if this was my data:

```
PTS, Ast, REB, BLK, STL
10   1    2    1    2
11   7    11   3    3
15   12   13   4    5
```

My result for the calculated field would be 0, 3, and 6 respectively.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following counts the number of fields greater than 10 in a subquery.  It then uses this value in the outer query to calculate the new field value:

```
select t.*,
       iif(NumGt10 >= 3 then 6, iif(NumGT10 >= 2, 3, 0)) as CalculatedField
from (select t.*,
             (iif(ppts >= 10, 1, 0) +
              iif(ast >= 10, 1, 0) +
              iif(reb >= 10, 1, 0) +
              iif(blk >= 10, 1, 0) +
              iif(stl>= 10, 1, 0)
             ) as NumGt10             
      from t
     ) t;
```